# How to specify the custom profile to send packet for Moongen?

Tags: packet, network-traffic, trafficshaping

I'm trying to send multiples packets to test a server , but i need to send different traffic pattern ( send IPv4,ICMP,Ipv6...) but i can't even specify one type when sending the streams

[EDIT-1]

CMD: `./build/MoonGen ./packetgen.lua -tx 0 -rx 1`
packetgen.lua is the default script present in LYA folder of Moongen

Comment: it looks like you are requesting information on usage of Moongen for sending multiple streams. Can you help us understand if you are using PCAP or custom lua script to send packets? If Lua script, please share error logs and script for your problem. Sample lua https://github.com/emmericp/MoonGen/blob/master/examples/netronome-packetgen/packetgen.lua. Since this specific to mooongen alternative is to get help from MoonGen community, github or author

Comment: Thank you for answering,in fact i'm trying to runn moongen with the lua scripts that are already found within the package,i'm using " ./build/MoonGen ./packetgen.lua -tx 0 -rx 1" to send traffic but the problem is that i cannot find the way to specify the stream profile like https or something like that

Comment: I have updated your question to reflect the problem as per the discussion in the comment. Can you check and approve the same?

Comment: Done , thank you very much